# Не срабатывает код jQuery

Tags: jquery

Имеется такая структура html:

```
<div class="shop-place col-md-3" id='over31'>
    <span>31-35</span>
    <div class="delete"></div>
</div>
```

К нему вот такой скрипт:

```
$('.delete').onclick = function() {
    this.parent('.shopPlace').style('display', 'none');
}
```

Танцы с бубном уже продолжаются больше часа, а скрипт и ныне там( Основная идея - скрыть блок .shop-place, при нажатии на вложенный div.delete

Comment: А по вашему `.shop-place` и `.shopPlace` - это равнозначные селекторы?

Comment: по-моему, да. Иначе же выдает ошибку при внесении .shop-place.

Comment: Если да, то тут уже никто вам не поможет :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.delete').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent('.shop-place').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shop-place col-md-3" id='over31'>
  <span>31-35</span>
  <div class="delete">x</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Так заработало. Не подскажете, где "черпнуть" особенностей синтаксиса?

Comment: @MaximRadziuk http://jquery.com/ , http://jquery.page2page.ru

Comment: Спасибо еще раз. Буду внимательней.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
   $('.delete').onclick = function() {
        $(this).closest('.shop-place').style('display', 'none');
    }
```

На будущее: `.shop-place` и `.shopPlace` разные селекторы.

```
   $('.delete').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.shop-place').style('display', 'none');
    });
```

Если элементы появляются динамически (с сервера):

```
   $(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
        $(this).closest('.shop-place').style('display', 'none');
    });
```

Comment: нет, не срабатывает.

Comment: @MaximRadziuk обновил ответ.

Comment: а как ты думаешь есть метод style в jq?

Comment: @Duoxx нет. есть `css`

Comment: @Tsyklop про `style` это тебе был намёк на твой ответ

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.delete').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.shop-place').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shop-place col-md-3" id='over31'>
    <span>31-35</span>
    <div class="delete">&times;</div>
</div>
```